# apache .htaccess rewrite rule - redirect example.com/login(/) to /login.php

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, apache2

I want do redirect /login to /login.php
My current rewrite rule is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^login login.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

example.com/login and example.com/login/ are already redirecting to /login.php. but if i type something after the last slash like example.com/login/**de9f02wr* is is also getting redirected to /login.php

i only want to redirect:
example.com/login optionally with a slash at the end
to /login.php

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `RewriteRule ^login/?$ login.php [L]`

Comment: You're welcome. I add it as answer. Thank you for validate it if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use real regex syntax to define your rules.

In your case, it will be :

```
RewriteRule ^login/?$ login.php [L]
```

The regex expression means :

```
- ^      -> Begin of the string,
- login  -> Matches literally "login", 
- /?     -> Conditional slash,
- $      -> End of the string.
```

Hope it helps.